# How to select all rows where a multiple column value occurs more than once in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to select all rows where a multiple column value occurs more than once in postgresql?
I want to find the rows which has same product_id and entry_date.

```
Input:
id     product_id  entry_date                   product_name stock
1      009         2020-12-11 02:05:20.09876    apple        5
2      001         2020-12-11 03:04:10.09876    orange       9
3      004         2020-12-11 10:05:20.09876    pineapple    4
4      002         2020-12-11 02:05:20.09876    berry        5
5      009         2020-12-11 02:05:20.09876    apple        2
6      004         2020-12-11 10:05:20.09876    pineapple    1
7      006         2020-12-11 10:05:20.09876    pineapple    4

select * from 
( select *, 
      count(1) over (partition by entry_date and product_id ) as occurs
from sale_order where entry_date::text LIKE '2020-12-11%'
) AS t where occurs > 1 ;

Output:
id     product_id  entry_date                   product_name stock
1      009         2020-12-11 02:05:20.09876    apple        5
3      004         2020-12-11 10:05:20.09876    pineapple    4
5      009         2020-12-11 02:05:20.09876    apple        2
6      004         2020-12-11 10:05:20.09876    pineapple    1
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Is the SQL you shared not producing the given output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window function - `count`  as follows

```
select * from
(select t.*,
       count(1) over (partition by product_id, entry_Date) as cnt
  from t) t
where cnt > 1
```

You can also use `exists` as follows:

```
select * from t
where exists
(select 1 from t tt
where t.product_id = tt.product_id
  and t.entry_Date = tt.entry_date
  and t.id <> tt.id)
```

Comment: If it solved your issue then you can accept the answer so that this question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with the `COUNT()` window function is quite correct - just change the syntax a little bit (replace `and` with `,`)

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=22589847cedea3f0092b1d6dfad5cd68)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY entry_date, product_id)
    FROM
        t
) s
WHERE count > 1
```

Additionally:

Instead of filtering your day with a string operation, you could simply cast the timestamp into date:

```
WHERE entry_date::date = '2020-12-11'
```